# Is it possible to search and replace a string with "any" characters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, replace

There are probably several ways to solve this problem, so I'm open to any ideas.

I have a file, within that file is the string "D133330593"   Note: I do have the exact position within the file this string exists, but I don't know if that helps.

Following this string, there are 6 digits, I need to replace these 6 digits with 6 other digits.

This is what I have so far:

```
def editfile():
    f = open(filein,'r')
    filedata = f.read()
    f.close()

    #This is the line that needs help

    newdata = filedata.replace( -TOREPLACE- ,-REPLACER-)

    #Basically what I need is something that lets me say "D133330593******" 
    #->"D133330593123456" Note: The following 6 digits don't need to be 
    #anything specific, just different from the original 6

    f = open(filein,'w')
    f.write(newdata)
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `re` module to define your pattern and then use the `sub()` function to substitute occurrence of that pattern with your own string.

```
import re

...

pat = re.compile(r"D133330593\d{6}")
re.sub(pat, "D133330593abcdef", filedata)
```

The above defines a pattern as -- your string ("D133330593") followed by six decimal digits. Then the next line replaces ALL occurrences of this pattern with your replacement string ("abcdef" in this case), if that is what you want.

If you want a unique replacement string for each occurrence of pattern, then you could use the `count` keyword argument in the `sub()` function, which allows you to specify the number of times the replacement must be done.

Check out this library for more info - https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html

Answer (score 2):

Let's simplify your problem to you having a `string`:

```
s = "zshisjD133330593090909fdjgsl"
```

and you wanting to replace the `6` characters after `"D133330593"` with `"123456"` to produce:

```
"zshisjD133330594123456fdjgsl"
```

To achieve this, we can first need to find the `index` of `"D133330593"`. This is done by just using `str.index`:

```
i = s.index("D133330593")
```

Then replace the next `6` `characters`, but for this, we should first calculate the length of our `string` that we want to replace:

```
l = len("D133330593")
```

then do the replace:

```
s[:i+l] + "123456" + s[i+l+6:]
```

which gives us the desired result of:

```
'zshisjD133330593123456fdjgsl'
```

I am sure that you can now integrate this into your code to work with a file, but this is how you can do the heart of your problem .

---

Note that using variables as above is the right thing to do as it is the most efficient compared to calculating them on the go. Nevertheless, if your `file` isn't too long (i.e. efficiency isn't too much of a big deal) you can do the whole process outlined above in one line:

```
s[:s.index("D133330593")+len("D133330593")] + "123456" + s[s.index("D133330593")+len("D133330593")+6:]
```

which gives the same result.